# How to overrule bottom alignment with top alignment when popup falls of the screen?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a web app (using Vue 3, but this question is not Vue-specific) which displays a list of items from a database. When the user clicks on an item, a popup menu shall appear. It shall be a "drop-up" menu, i.e. the bottom shall be aligned with the selected item. However, if that would mean that the popup falls over the top edge of the window, the popup shall be aligned with the top of the window.

Please run the example below. It shows only one item, Apple (normally I have a long list). Imagine the user has clicked on Apple. The app shows a list of fruits, but the first ones are not visible. I have omitted the dynamic Vue part (using onclick to show/hide the popup).

How can I keep the bottom alignment by default, but override it if and only if the popup falls over the top edge of the window? Is there a CSS solution or is Javascript required? Any answer is appreciated, using your own favourite Javascript framework.

```css
.button {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.drop-up {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  padding: 2px 20px;
}

.drop-up-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  bottom: 25px;  
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
  <p>Test drop-up</h2>
  <div class="button drop-up">
    Apple
    <div class="drop-up-content">
      <div class="button">Apple</div>
      <div class="button">Banana</div>
      <div class="button">Grape</div>
      <div class="button">Lemon</div>
      <div class="button">Pear</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: since the popup can be anywhere in the page you will need JS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif,  How can I check in JavaScript that the popup is over the edge of the window?

Comment: check this: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/

Answer (score 0):

With help from @TemaniAfif, I found the following solution: When the "drop-up" is shown, test if it falls off the screen using `getBoundingClientRect()` and if it does, move it by changing the class.

```js
function onSubmit(event) {
  const box = event.target.children.namedItem('dropUp');
  if (box.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0) {
    box.setAttribute("class", "drop-up-content top-aligned");
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.drop-up {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  padding: 2px 20px;
}

.drop-up-content {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bottom-aligned {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
}

.top-aligned {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Test drop-up</h2>
  <div class="button drop-up" onclick="onSubmit(event)">
    Apple (click here)
    <div id="dropUp" class="drop-up-content bottom-aligned">
      <div class="button">Apple</div>
      <div class="button">Banana</div>
      <div class="button">Grape</div>
      <div class="button">Lemon</div>
      <div class="button">Pear</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```